# How to translate this chinese saying?

Tags: translation

Im going to get a tattoo soon, and I was searching ideas on the internet and I come up with this chinese saying (view death as simply returning to where one came from) which apparently means not fearing death. Can someone by any means help me on how the saying would be like in chinese .
I would appreciate it !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 视死如归 seen as "See death as returning home"(Respect to someone who died) or "Not afraid of death"(arrogance)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/is-%e8%a7%86%e6%ad%bb%e5%a6%82%e5%bd%92-seen-as-see-death-as-returning-homerespect-to-someone-who-died-or-n)

Answer (score 1):

[視死如歸](https://idiom.wlps.kl.edu.tw/dict_idioms/678.html)

/shì sǐ rú guī/

> 釋義: 把犧牲生命看成是回到自己的家一般，

> Meaning: Think of sacrificing life as returning to one's own home

視 = see

死 = death

如 = as

歸 = return; go back

視死如歸 = see death as going home (meaning 'not afraid of dying' - 不怕死)

Simplified Chinese: 视死如归

*Note: Use traditional characters if your audience is Taiwan or Hong Kong Chinese; use simplified Chinese if your audience is Mainland China Chinese*

Answer (score 0):

It is spoken: shì sǐ rú guī

把死看得好像回家一样。
Regard death like coming home.

形容为了正义的事业，不怕死。
(It) describes in the name of justice, no fear of death.

《吕氏春秋·勿躬》：
Mr. Lü's Spring and Autumn, Wu Gong (@239BC)

“三军之士，视死如归。”
All soldiers, regard(视shì) death (死sǐ) as (如rú) returning (归guī) .

归：回家。
returning: returning home.

What lamentable home lives they must have had!!